# Adding library from GAC into source control and project references

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 project which uses some Interop libraries (mainly `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`). In order to get these projects to build in an Azure DevOps pipeline, I am trying to add these into source control (git). I've copied these dll files from the GAC folder into a `libs` folder in my project.

However, when I go via Project -> Add Reference and select those files, the vbproj file seems to have added these as if they were still in the GAC. Selecting the reference properties in VS2022 looks like this:

[image: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook properties]

Even after I have manually edited the vbproj file to use a hint path like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook">
    <HintPath>..\..\libs\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

This seems to have no effect, and the project still gets the dll from the GAC, which means this won't build in a DevOps pipeline which doesn't have these libraries available.

How can I add these dlls to source control and ensure my project uses them to build, so that they can be used in DevOps?

Comment: Have you actually tried it in the pipeline?  Just because it gets it from the GAC on your local machine doesn't mean it will do the same thing on the build agent.  I'd also suggest that you might want to consider doing this through a NuGet package instead of putting the binaries into your source control.

Comment: Yes, the pipeline fails due to not having these libraries (or the right versions).

Comment: You can add NuGet packages to DevOps under Artifacts. That's how you should be accessing these libraries when building.

Comment: Seems like there might be something more complicated going on; the reference as given seems like it ought to work acceptably on the pipeline.  Maybe another library that still has a different reference?

Comment: @Craig I've found other answers which state that DevOps doesn't have all (any?) COM library references, or at least not the ones which are only installed on a user's machine if they have MS Office installed. I don't think there's any other libraries that still reference it... I'll double check tomorrow.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if another developer clones the repo, can VS use a DevOps Artifacts feed similar to a NuGet feed source?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I setup a feed in DevOps, however the source DevOps provides is not valid in Visual Studio. Classic.